# I want to install openresty in my ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-11.10, remote-installation

I had downloaded ngx_openresty-1.2.6.6.tar.gz (stable release) from http://openresty.org/
and I had done these commands on terminal:

```
tar xzvf ngx_openresty-VERSION.tar.gz
cd ngx_openresty-VERSION/
./configure --with-luajit
make
make install
```

i was not able to install openresty in my computer. I belive that make install command doesn't works out, because it prompts me error when I go with `make install`.

(etc...+)
==== Installing LuaJIT 2.0.0 to /usr/local/openresty/luajit ====
mkdir -p /usr/local/openresty/luajit/bin /usr/local/openresty/luajit/lib /usr/local/openresty/luajit/include/luajit-2.0 /usr/local/openresty/luajit/share/man/man1 /usr/local/openresty/luajit/lib/pkgconfig /usr/local/openresty/luajit/share/luajit-2.0.0/jit /usr/local/openresty/luajit/share/lua/5.1 /usr/local/openresty/luajit/lib/lua/5.1
cd src && install -m 0755 luajit /usr/local/openresty/luajit/bin/luajit-2.0.0
install: cannot remove `/usr/local/openresty/luajit/bin/luajit-2.0.0': Permission denied
make[1]: *** [install] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory`/ngx_openresty-1.2.6.6/build/LuaJIT-2.0.0'
make: *** [install] Error 2

Please let me know the way to get openresty installed on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

You need permission to install under /usr/local directory.

try using sudo command as

```
sudo make install
```

NOTE: If it ask for password, enter your user password. If that doesn't work than

1. you need to install as root  or
2. change installation directory to where you have access e.g echo $HOME

   ```
   ./configure --with-luajit  --prefix=$HOME

   make

   make install
   ```

Once it is install, follow "Getting Started" link on http://openresty.org/

Comment: Let me know the way to determine whether openresty is installed in my system or not?

Comment: @yser212063 I have updated answer with the link on validation step by starting openresty. Did steps given in my answer resolved your installation issue?

Comment: i feel that this command "sudo make install" works. But i don't know how far it worked in installation process successfully. So i need to find out whether it gets installed or not.

Comment: execute  'sudo updatedb'  and than  'locate openresty'  (without single quotes).  it will show you the openresty installation directory.

Comment: yes, it is showing some directory paths. might i know,this was the only means to have determine openresty has intalled or not.